# How To Keep the Arrow Pointing Up When the Dropdown Is Visible?

Tags: html, css, hover, dropdown

I need help. I have a main button that has an arrow pointing down to indicate that there is a dropdown. Upon hover, the dropdown appears and the arrow rotates and pointing up. However, it should keep pointing up when I hover over the dropdown items. Could anyone help me with my codes? Thank you in advance.

Please see the link for codes on CodePen.
https://codepen.io/denzdoneza/pen/ZEjddQp

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="mainButton">
  <button>Resources<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 24 14.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 24 14.1;" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M12,14.1L0,2.1L2.1,0L12,9.9L21.8,0L24,2.2L12,14.1z"/>
</svg></button>
</a>
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#"><button>Blackpaper</button></a>
  <a href="#"><button>Whitepaper</button></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
button {
  width: 256px;
  height: 52px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #cd0d0d;
  color: #ffffff;
}
a button svg {
  fill: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 6px 0 0 8px;
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #8e0000;
}
a.mainButton:hover ~ .dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
a.mainButton:hover svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
.dropdown:hover {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.dropdown:hover ~ a.mainButton button svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) !important;
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
```

I tried a CSS :hover on the container of the dropdown and use ~ to point on the arrow but it didn't work.

CSS:

```
.dropdown:hover ~ a.mainButton button svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) !important;
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put all the code inside a container and then change:

```
a.mainButton:hover svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
```

For:

```
.container:hover svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 256px;
  height: 52px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #cd0d0d;
  color: #ffffff;
}
a button svg {
  fill: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 6px 0 0 8px;
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}
a.mainButton:hover ~ .dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container:hover svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
.dropdown:hover {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.dropdown a:hover ~ a.mainButton button svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) !important;
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<a href="#" class="mainButton">
  <button>Resources<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 24 14.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 24 14.1;" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M12,14.1L0,2.1L2.1,0L12,9.9L21.8,0L24,2.2L12,14.1z"/>
</svg></button>
</a>
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#"><button>Blackpaper</button></a>
  <a href="#"><button>Whitepaper</button></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75412436/19703733
Thank you! I should have added a div container on top of the main button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the CSS rule "pointer-events: none" under the display: none; line

```
.dropdown {
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alon, welcome to SO! Have you tested this? It makes no sense to disable pointer events as *all* mouse actions of `dropdown` will now be ignored.

Comment: I apologize. I will run the code on my computer and update the response.